# set correct request host to avoid this infinite loop in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect, cache, 301-redirect

I configured this nginx server for `example.com` and `www.example.com` to be a cache/reverse proxy, taking data from mysource.example.com

It seems to work ok in browser, but I noticed significant google rankings drop, and when I tested the URL with wget, I get an infinite loop.

```
# test without www , getting infinite loop
wget --header="Host: example.com" http://[SERVER IP]/file.html


Location: https://www.example.com/file.html [following]
--2020-02-07 21:43:14--  https://www.example.com/file.html
Reusing existing connection to www.example.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.example.com/file.html [following]
20 redirections exceeded.
^^^ RIGHT HERE !!!

# but with www it works OK:
wget --header="Host: www.example.com" http://[SERVER IP]/file.html


HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1307 (1.3K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘file.html’
```

I think I need to specify another `host` in the redirect from non www to www ?!

Or is this just a **wget thing** because it normally should switch to the www.example.com on first redirect but it keeps the non-www host from the nginx command ?

```
# redirect http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_name www.example.com;

    proxy_set_header Host      www.example.com
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


# and redirect non www to www
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    proxy_set_header Host      www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


# main server, SSL
server {

    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    location / {

            proxy_pass       http://mysource.example.com:81;

            proxy_set_header Host      www.example.com;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_cache             nginx_ramdisk_cache;
    }



} # end of server
```

Comment: My guess is that those spurious redirects are generated by `http://mysource.example.com:81`. What software are you using there?

Comment: the source server is using Apache, it has all redirects disabled on that one, and I tested now another wget like above, but accessing the source server directly, it works with both header hosts (with / without www): `wget --header="Host: example.com" http://source.example.com:81/file.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you use `wget`. By using:

```
wget --header="Host: example.com" http://example.com/file.html
```

you replace the `Host` header of **every** request that **wget** will perform. So:

1. wget connects to port `80` of your server and gets redirected to `https://www.example.com/file.html`,
2. wget connects to port `443` of your server, but sends the `Host: example.com` header instead of `Host: www.example.com`. It get redirected to `https://www.example.com/file.html`,
3. We are back at 2.

So, your config is fine, there was just a problem in your test. You should never override the `Host` header, **wget** will automatically set it to the domain in the URL.